# Managing trunk and feature branches: local delete, incoming delete upon merge

Tags: svn, merge, conflict

I am using svn with a feature branch scheme. Whenever I try to merge trunk to a branch, I got the problem "local delete, incoming delete upon merge". It does not make sense to me.
What I did to reproduce the error:
1) create a branch with "svn copy ^/blabla/trunk ^/blabla/branches/test-merge"
2) add a new file to trunk "touch t.c ; svn add t.c ; svn commit"
3) merge to trunk to branch "svn merge ^/blabla/trunk ^/blabla/branches/test-merge"
The output is:

```
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
 C t.c
Summary of conflicts:
 Tree conflicts: 1
```

I am using version "1.6.17 (r1128011)"

Resolving the conflict manually (with svn accept) does not help. The new file does not appear in the branch and a new merge results in the same conflict.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. I'm afraid, but without **real log of all used commands** I have to say "You couldn't get tree conflict in process" 2. sidenote: 2-URL merge was bad choice

Comment: Here are all the commands I used to reproduce the error: `mkdir svn`
`cd ~/tmp`
`svnadmin create svn`
`svn mkdir file:///home/adenilso/tmp/svn/mtree`
`svn mkdir file:///home/adenilso/tmp/svn/mtree/trunk`
`svn mkdir file:///home/adenilso/tmp/svn/mtree/branches`
`mkdir localws`
`cd localws`
`svn co file:///home/adenilso/tmp/svn/mtree`
`cd mtree`
`svn copy ^/mtree/trunk ^/mtree/branches/test-reintegrate`
`ls`
`svn up`
`cd trunk`
`touch t.c`
`svn add t.c`
`svn commit`
`cd ..`
`cd branches`
`cd test-reintegrate`
`svn merge ^/mtree/trunk ^/mtree/branches/test-reintegrate`
Then I got the conflict@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extraction from `svn help merge`

> 4 This form is called a '2-URL merge':
>
> ```
>   svn merge SOURCE1[@N] SOURCE2[@M] [TARGET_WCPATH]
> ```
>
> Two source URLs are specified, together with two revisions N and M.
>        The two sources are compared at the specified revisions, and the
>        difference is applied to TARGET_WCPATH, which is a path to a **working
>        copy of another branch**.

I'll skip some preliminary steps before merge and will use Win-style paths in some places (no bash here, sorry) and slightly change workflow (branch will be non-empty)

```
z:\>dir /B
svn
localws
```

---

```
z:\>dir localws /B /S
z:\localws\mtree
...
z:\localws\mtree\branches
z:\localws\mtree\trunk
```

---

```
z:\>svn ls -v -R file:///Z:/svn/mtree
      3 Badger                окт 13 21:30 ./
      3 Badger                окт 13 21:30 branches/
      2 Badger                окт 13 21:29 trunk/
```

(repo and WC prepared, but still empty)

---

Files created and commited to trunk

```
z:\>dir /B z:\localws\mtree\trunk
1.txt
2.txt

z:\>svn ls -v -R file:///Z:/svn/mtree
      4 Badger                окт 13 21:48 ./
      3 Badger                окт 13 21:30 branches/
      4 Badger                окт 13 21:48 trunk/
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/1.txt
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/2.txt
```

---

Branch initiated

```
Z:\localws\mtree\trunk>svn copy file:///Z:/svn/mtree/trunk file:///Z:/svn/mtree/branches/test-reintegrate -m "Create test-reintegrate branch"

Committed revision 5.
```

Test it

```
Z:\localws\mtree\trunk>svn ls -v -R file:///Z:/svn/mtree
      5 Badger                окт 13 22:17 ./
      5 Badger                окт 13 22:17 branches/
      5 Badger                окт 13 22:17 branches/test-reintegrate/
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 branches/test-reintegrate/1.txt
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 branches/test-reintegrate/2.txt
      4 Badger                окт 13 21:48 trunk/
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/1.txt
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/2.txt
```

and get updated WC after `svn up` in Z:\localws\mtree

```
Z:\localws\mtree>dir /B /S
Z:\localws\mtree\branches
Z:\localws\mtree\trunk
...
Z:\localws\mtree\branches\test-reintegrate\2.txt
Z:\localws\mtree\branches\test-reintegrate\1.txt
Z:\localws\mtree\trunk\1.txt
Z:\localws\mtree\trunk\2.txt
```

---

Added new file to trunk, edited file in branch

```
Z:\localws\mtree>svn log -v -r6:7
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2012-10-13 22:28:04 +0600 (Сб, 13 окт 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /mtree/trunk/3.txt

Added new file to trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2012-10-13 22:29:20 +0600 (Сб, 13 окт 2012) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /mtree/branches/test-reintegrate/2.txt

Some changes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Server-side view

```
Z:\localws\mtree>svn ls -v -R file:///Z:/svn/mtree
      7 Badger                окт 13 22:29 ./
      7 Badger                окт 13 22:29 branches/
      7 Badger                окт 13 22:29 branches/test-reintegrate/
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 branches/test-reintegrate/1.txt
      7 Badger             17 окт 13 22:29 branches/test-reintegrate/2.txt
      6 Badger                окт 13 22:28 trunk/
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/1.txt
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 trunk/2.txt
      6 Badger              9 окт 13 22:28 trunk/3.txt
```

---

Sync branch with trunk - merge changes **from trunk to test-reintegrate**

```
Z:\localws\mtree>cd branches

Z:\localws\mtree\branches>cd test-reintegrate
Z:\localws\mtree\branches\test-reintegrate>svn merge file:///Z:/svn/mtree/trunk
--- Merging r5 through r7 into '.':
A    3.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r5 through r7 into '.':
 U   .
```

Check WC state

```
Z:\localws\mtree\branches\test-reintegrate>dir /B
2.txt
1.txt
3.txt
```

and commit results

```
Z:\localws\mtree\branches\test-reintegrate>svn commit -m "Sync of test-reintegrate"
Sending        .
Adding         3.txt

Committed revision 8.
```

Server-side

```
Z:\>svn ls -v file:///Z:/svn/mtree/branches/test-reintegrate
      8 Badger                окт 13 22:47 ./
      4 Badger              9 окт 13 21:48 1.txt
      7 Badger             17 окт 13 22:29 2.txt
      8 Badger              9 окт 13 22:47 3.txt
```

## Resume

My changes in comparison to your style (and "win ws fail" result)

- Full path without ^ shorthand (I got error even on `svn copy` stage, AFAIK ^ recommended and usable in case of "branch in the root of WC" style, not combined common WC /but I could be wrong/)
- Using classic form of merge (Single URL)

HTH

Comment: Hi Lazy Badger, I worked!  was using the 2-url, ^-started merge. I tried it as you suggested and now the behavior is as expected. Somehow I assumed the 2-url was the expected way to do the merge. Thank you.

Comment: @user1740800 - 2URL merge (as noted in help) will work, when you merge 2 branches into **third** (probably unrelated to sources), checkouted in WC